# Смена background-color у div через js не происходит

Tags: javascript, html, background

Есть код:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('fon1');

var retObj = 1;
if(retObj == "1") {
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
};
```

```css
.fon1 { 
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.fon1:hover { 
   background-color: #E1E7FA;
}    

.fon1>img { 
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px; 
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div id="fon1" class="fon1">
    <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">
    <for>Текст1</for>    
    <for1>Текст2</for1>
  </div>
</a>
```

Таких дивов как в коде несколько. При нажатии, они меняют значение переменной. У меня прописано условие, что если значение переменной равно такому-то числу, то необходимо поменять `background-color` дива, как у обычного, так и у `hover`. Но пока даже с обычном не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть дело?

Comment: В hover из JS для конкретного блока вы не сможете задать цвет. Псевдоклассы недоступны в JS. В остальном посмотрите в консоль на предмет ошибок и проверьте что попадает в переменную div

Comment: В сниппете Ваш серый цвет устанавливается

Comment: он ругается на эту строчку: "div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';"

"Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kuraborg/

записал таким способом, перестал ругаться, но все толку нет

Comment: "В сниппете Ваш серый цвет устанавливается"
поясните пожалуйста

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kuraborg/1/ - сделал вот так. Все работает, но почему-то только после нажатия на фон сайта - тогда меняется backgroundcolor у дива...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняйте не цвет элемента, а класс, на который в `css` можно подвесить другой цвет:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('fon1');

var retObj = 1;
if (retObj == "1") {
  div.classList.add('active');
} else {
  div.classList.remove('active');
};
```

```css
.fon1 {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.fon1:hover {
  background-color: #E1E7FA;
}

.fon1 > img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
}

.fon1.active {
  background-color: grey;
}

.fon1.active:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div id="fon1" class="fon1">
    <img src="/images/main3.jpg" alt="текст">
    <for>Текст1</for>
    <for1>Текст2</for1>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: К сожалению не меняется..

Comment: Не меняется что именно? Класс `.active` у элемента?

Comment: Вот как всё сейчас выглядит: https://jsfiddle.net/kuraborg/2/

И по идеи, там видно что работает.. а у меня почему-то background-color не меняется у дива..

Comment: Зачем вы присваиваете где-то `.active2`, а где-то `.active`? Присваивайте везде `.active`, в стилях у вас конфликтов из-за этого не будет.

Comment: убрал, но легче не стало.. ( цвет дива не хочет меняться почему-то

Comment: По проблемному элементу что видите в инспекторе объектов? http://i.imgur.com/2jo2wKW.png

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59600/discussion-between---and-user250973).

Comment: Для чата мне нужно вспоминать логин и пароль от этого сайта.. Сайт выдаёт ошибку: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Comment: Все, проблема решена. Просто скрипт выполнялся до того как прогрузится разметка.